# Angular: Make Post Request From ErrorHandler?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling

I am trying to send any errors, exceptions that Angular is catching to my server. I made my own class called GlobalErrorHandler that is extending ErrorHandler. Please check below

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from "@angular/core";
```

import {HttpHeaders, HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { TestServiceService } from "../_services/test-service.service";

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private service: TestServiceService,
  ) {}

  url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/post';

  handleError(error) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
      };

    try {

      let msg = JSON.parse(error)
      console.log('>>>>>>>>> message is ', msg)
      this.http.post(this.url, msg, httpOptions);

    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log('>>>>>>>>> err in catch is ', e)
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to console.error(error) whenever an error occurs, but I cannot make a post request to my server.

What am I missing in my code to make post request from ErrorHandler?

Comment: Json parse `error` and send

Comment: no good, tried JSON.parse(error) that line never runs. Is that what you meant?

Comment: this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(error), httpOptions) is i think what Lasitha meant

Comment: @JonathanKelsey exactly. my mistake.

Comment: try capturing any error with this.http.post directly and console.error it. Currently we are kinda blind to your issue.

Comment: JSON.stringify(error) returns an empty object. Let me put a try catch in there and see what happens

Comment: ok made some edit. I'm getting  SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 error when trying to parse the error.

Comment: I also tried error.toString() with no luck btw.

Comment: Your try catch wont work i dont think as this.http.post is an observable. Do it like this: https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling

Comment: it's catching the error though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177758/discussion-between-jonathan-kelsey-and-generaldeep).

Answer (score 0):

After changing the code to the following (replacing JSON.parse with JSON.stringify and catching the post errors successfully):

```
handleError(error) { 
    const httpOptions = { 
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) 
    }; 

    let subscription = this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(error), httpOptions).subscribe( 
        (data => {console.log('>>>>>>> data is ', data));subscription.unsubscribe();}, 
        error => {console.log('>>>>>>>> err', error);subscription.unsubscribe();}
    )

}
```

The error was discovered to be on the serverside, but the code above should be useful to anyone trying to trasmit clientside errors(in Angular2+) to the server provided that the server has been implemented correctly.